# Outer Class Member Variable Null To Inner Class

Tags: java, inner-classes, private-members, jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

I am working on a game using JME3 and Nifty GUI. I have an outer class that has a `Nifty` member variable. And the inner class should be able to access that variable regardless of access modifier. In the constructor I assign a new `Nifty` object to it. However when I access that variable in the inner class I run into problems. I did a little debugging and found out it's because the inner class thinks the `Nifty` member variable is null and I cant figure out why. Its not null in the outer class. Since this is a JME3 game I tried to have the inner class implement the `AppState` interface but it still shows the `Nifty` member variable as null. Here is the code:

```
public class MenuScreen extends SimpleApplication {



/** Used to configure Nifty GUI. */
private Nifty mNifty;

private NiftyJmeDisplay mNiftyDisplay;


private Element popup;

//*******************
// Overridden medhods
//*******************

/** This method is used to initialize everything needed to display the game screen. */
@Override
public void simpleInitApp() {
    guiNode.detachAllChildren();

    initNifty();

    flyCam.setDragToRotate(true);
}

/**
 * The game's main update loop.
 * 
 * @param tpf Time Per Fram, the time it takes each loop to run.
 */
@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
    // not used
}

@Override
public void simpleRender(RenderManager rm) {
    // not used
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MenuScreen app = new MenuScreen();
    app.start();
}

/**
* Helper method to initialize and configure Nifty GUI.
*/
private void initNifty() {        
    mNiftyDisplay = new NiftyJmeDisplay(assetManager, inputManager, audioRenderer, guiViewPort);
    mNifty = mNiftyDisplay.getNifty();

    guiViewPort.addProcessor(mNiftyDisplay);

    // If this is being run on a desktop then load the desktop main menu.
    if (Strings.OS_NAME.contains("windows") || Strings.OS_NAME.contains("mac") || Strings.OS_NAME.contains("linux")) {
        mNifty.fromXml("Interface/XML/DesktopMenuScreenGui.xml", "start", new MenuScreen().new MenuScreenGui());
    }
    // If its an Android device load the mobile main menu.
    else if (Strings.OS_NAME.contains("android")) {
        mNifty.fromXml("Interface/XML/MobileMenuScreenGui.xml", "mobile", new MenuScreen().new MenuScreenGui());
    }
}

//**************
// Inner Classes
//**************

/**
 * © Jason Crosby 2012 <p>
 * 
 * This class handles all the GUI interactions like button clicks.
 * 
 * @author Jason Crosby
 */
public class MenuScreenGui implements ScreenController, EventTopicSubscriber<MenuItemActivatedEvent>,
                                      AppState {

    @Override
    public void initialize(AppStateManager stateManager, Application app) {

    }
@Override
    public void cleanup() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInitialized() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void postRender() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean active) {

    }

    @Override
    public void stateAttached(AppStateManager stateManager) {

    }

    @Override
    public void stateDetached(AppStateManager stateManager) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(RenderManager rm) {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float tpf) {

    }
    @Override
    public void bind(Nifty nifty, Screen screen) {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndScreen() {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartScreen() {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(String string, MenuItemActivatedEvent t) {

    }

    //**************
    // Class methods
    //**************

    /**
     * Called when the play button is clicked.
     */
    public void playButton() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the high scores button is clicked.
     */
    public void highScoresButton() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the settings button is clicked.
     */
    public void settingsButton() {

    }
    public void quitButton() {
        showDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the rate button is clicked. Only Available on mobile.
     */
    public void rateButton() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the feedback button is clicked. Only on mobile devices.
     */
    public void feedbackButton() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the help button is clicked.
     */
    public void helpButton() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the dialog needs to be shown.
     */
    public void showDialog() {
        System.out.println("WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW");
        popup = new Nifty().createPopup("popup");
        System.out.println("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ");
        //Menu myMenu = popup.findNiftyControl("#menu", Menu.class);
        //myMenu.setWidth(new SizeValue("100px")); // must be set
        //myMenu.addMenuItem("Click me!", new menuItem("menuItemid", "blah blah")); // menuItem is a custom class
        //mNifty.subscribe(mNifty.getCurrentScreen(), myMenu.getId(), MenuItemActivatedEvent.class, this);
        mNifty.showPopup(mNifty.getCurrentScreen(), popup.getId(), null); 
    }

    public void clsoseDialog() {

    }

    /**
     * Used to return a String to the Nifty xml file.
     * 
     * @param name The name key associated with the String.
     * @return The String associated with the key.
     */
    public String getString(String name) {
        if (name.equals("play")) {
            return Strings.PLAY_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("high_score")) {
            return Strings.HIGH_SCORES_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("settings")) {
            return Strings.SETTINGS_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("quit")) {
            return Strings.QUIT_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("rate")) {
            return Strings.RATE_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("feedback")) {
            return Strings.FEEDBACK_BUTTON;
        }
        else if (name.equals("rules")) {
            return Strings.RULES_BUTTON;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

What happens is I click on the quit button which calls the `quitButton()` method. That works fine. That in turn invokes `showDialog()` which is where the problem is. In the `showDialog()` method is this line `popup = new Nifty().createPopup("popup");` and it is at that line which `mNifty` is null when it shouldn't be. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
popup = new Nifty().createPopup("popup");
```

does not use `mNifty`. It creates a new instance of `Nifty` and then calls `creatPopup()` on this new instance. Since earlier you initialized `mNifty` by calling what looks like a factory method

```
mNifty = mNiftyDisplay.getNifty();
```

it is quite possible that obtaining a `Nifty` via `new` does not return a completely initialized instance.  Since you haven't posted the code for `Nifty` it is unclear what is happening.

I would double-check to make sure that creating a `Nifty` via `new` will return a fully initialized instance, and that you really wanted a new instance here.

Comment: Sweet I'll check that as soon as I get a chance. I'll also try to find the source code for the Nifty gui and see what is in the constructor vs the getNifty method.

Comment: I tried it out and unfortunately mNifty is still null inside the inner class.

Comment: I also tried to put the `showDialog()` method in the outer class and it still didn't work.

Comment: I also changed mNifty to static and now mNifty is no longer null when in the inner class. However no popup dialog shows. Do you have any other suggestions?